# Django: Extended User Model Cant Save

Tags: django, django-forms

I have extended the django user model with another model called profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chosenCharity = models.ForeignKey('meta.Charity', db_column='chosenCharityid', related_name='user_chosenCharity')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

When I try to create a new user within the view with the code below i get the following error "(1048, "Column 'chosenCharityid' cannot be null")":

```
@transaction.atomic
def register(request):
    selectedTeams = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(Q(teamid=request.session['team1id']) | Q(teamid=request.session['team2id'])).order_by('teamname')
    request.POST.get('currentCharities')

    next_url = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', reverse('straightred.payment')))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
```

I know when a user has already created I should be able to use:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
user.profile.chosenCharity = 12
user.save()
```

But I am unsure how to do this when creating the user.  Any help would be appreciated.

Below is a copy of the registration form to help:

```
class RegistrationForm(BootstrapModelForm, UserCreationForm):
    email_opt_in = forms.BooleanField(label='Receive DWAD e-mail updates', required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # The default Django user model doesn't require these fields to be set
        # but we do.

        self.fields['email'].required = True

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError('There is already an account registered with this e-mail address.')
        return email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username']
```

Charity Model:

```
class Charity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    website = models.URLField()
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'charities'
```

Comment: chosenCharity cannot be null when saving the profile object in create_user_profile signal receiver. Profile needs a charity id. If it is optional make null=True on your chosenCharity field.

Comment: Hello Zap, it is not optional but I just don't know how to set it in the view.  Any thoughts?

Comment: do you have the charity id available in the request.POST data? Instead of using the post_save signal you can create a profile object right after new_user = form.save()

Comment: I have it available in "request.session['chosenCharityid']".  But I cant' use do anything after the new_user - form.save().  Are you saying my only option is to remove the autocreate and just save the profile straight after?

Comment: profile needs a charity id. there is no easy direct way to supply profile a charity id in post_save. Yes, you need to save profile object where you can supply it a charity id. Why can't you do anything after form.save()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't create the Profile object in post_save signal. You cannot access the required charity id in `create_user_profile` method. So remove that part of code.

instead save the profile object right after you save your user object in your `register` view like this:

```
@transaction.atomic
def register(request):
    selectedTeams = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(Q(teamid=request.session['team1id']) | Q(teamid=request.session['team2id'])).order_by('teamname')
    request.POST.get('currentCharities')

    next_url = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', reverse('straightred.payment')))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            charity_id = request.session['chosenCharityid']
            # create profile object
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user, chosenCharity_id=charity_id)
```

EDIT:

I see that you are using another method `save_user_profile` to receive the post_save signal.

Don't use this either. It a round about way of doing a simple straight forward thing.

Using you own code sample:

```py
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
# here you are assigning a new charity id to the profile object
user.profile.chosenCharity = 12
# you save the user object on which nothing has changed
# instead you should save the profile object
user.save() # no need
user.profile.save() # direct and logical
```

Comment: I do appreciate your help but this just gives me "global name 'Profile' is not defined".

Comment: where is the profile model defined? can you check if it is imported correctly

Comment: There is something wrong with my Charity model.  Ignore me while I go fix that:(

Comment: Everything looks right but I just get the following error still: User has no profile.

Comment: on which line are you getting this error? Have you removed both the post save signal methods?

Comment: Progress!  I didn't import Profile (basic error by me).  But I now get: "Profile.chosenCharity" must be a "Charity" instance.

Comment: @AlanTingey i have edited the answer. the field name should be `chosenCharity_id` when creating the profile object. Make sure the id of the charity saved in the session object.

Comment: @AlanTingey glad to be of help!